# worker causing wierd problems and i dont know why - python

Tags: python, pyqt, qthread

So basically I created a script called worker which contain 2 classes:
Worker
CreateThread

this script is supposed to handle unexpected exception occurs, while also provide threading solution to running heavy function to prevent GUI freezing.

My problem is that I get unexpected behavior sometimes, for example one time I can run function with the worker class and I will get a good response and everything works fine, and second time things go wrong and I get odd errors and also GUI crashes.

I tried to change the order I manage the thread handling, and I tried addepting the code to the errors but there is a hidden problem that keeps hunting me...

that is my worker code:

```
# Create a worker class #
class Worker(QObject):
    my_started = pyqtSignal()
    my_finished = pyqtSignal()
    my_error = pyqtSignal(str, str)
    my_success = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

    def run(self, func):
        try:
            self.my_started.emit()
            time.sleep(0.1)
            x = func()
            if x is None:
                self.my_success.emit()
                self.my_finished.emit()
                return

            if x[0] == -1:
                function_error = x[1]
                trace_back = x[2]
                print(f'\nFunction error: {function_error}')
                print(trace_back)
                self.my_error.emit(str(function_error), trace_back,
                                   str(func.__name__))
                self.my_finished.emit()
                return

        except Exception as e:
            self.trace_back = str(traceback.format_exc())
            print(f'\nFunction error: {e}')
            print(self.trace_back)
            self.my_error.emit(str(e), self.trace_back)

        self.my_finished.emit()


# Creating thread manger class #
class CreateThread(Worker, QObject):

    def __init__(self, atp_name):
        super(CreateThread, self).__init__()
        self.stop_flag = False
        self.atp_name = atp_name
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()

    def start_thread(self, func, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

        self.func_name = func.__name__

        if self.stop_flag:
            return

        if self.func_name == '<lambda>':
            self.func_name = self.kwargs['func_name']

        # Thread and Worker init #
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()
        act = partial(self.worker.run, func)
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(act)

        # Signal to Function connection #
        self.worker.my_started.connect(self.started_signal_connection)
        self.worker.my_finished.connect(self.finished_signal_connection)
        self.worker.my_error.connect(self.error_signal_connection)
        self.worker.my_success.connect(self.success_signal_connection)

        # Handling the worker and the thread deletion #
        self.worker.my_finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.my_finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)

        self.thread.start()

    # Connect signals from worker #
    def started_signal_connection(self):
        self.stop_flag = True
        print(f"\nFunction {self.func_name} started\n")

    def finished_signal_connection(self):
        self.stop_flag = False
        print("\nWorker finished\n")

    def error_signal_connection(self, error_name, trace_back):
        self.today = date.today()
        self.now = datetime.now()
        self.current_date = str(
            self.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")).replace(' ',
                                                            '_').replace(
            '/', '_').replace(':', '_')
        self.header_name = f'{self.atp_name}_{self.func_name}_Date_{self.current_date}'
        self.target_folder = 'target_folder'

        if os.path.isfile(self.header_name) == False:
            file_name = f'{self.target_folder}{self.header_name}.txt'
            try:
                with open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    f.write(f'''ATP: {self.atp_name}\nFunction name: {self.func_name}\nError: {error_name}\nDate: {self.current_date}\n\n{trace_back}''')
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

    def success_signal_connection(self):
        self.stop_flag = False
        print("\nFunction success")
```

Another thing I noticed is that every time I use the worker with function that use Tk - askopenfilename()
I get troubles, here is a traceback example:

```
line 57, in run

**x = func()**

line 64, in open_main_terminal

**self.path1, self.file_name = upload_item()**

line 62, in upload_item

**filename = askopenfilename()**

line 375, in askopenfilename

**return Open(**options).show()**

line 39, in show

**w = Frame(self.master)**

line 2741, in __init__

**Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)**

line 2296, in __init__ (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))

**RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop**
```

Comment: Trying to use Tkinter and Qt in the same app is your first mistake.

Comment: Your code and concepts have **lots** of issues (other than trying to use Tk with Qt). Then, I can only assume (as your code is quite convoluted and difficult to understand) that you're trying to show or interact with UI elements from an external thread, which is normally a terrible choice, as almost any UI toolkit considers widgets as ***NOT*** thread-safe. I don't know about Tk, but in Qt the **only** way to communicate to the UI from an external thread is by using signals. If you don't do that, your program will not be *safe* (hence the "thread-safe" concept). That's why it crashes.

Comment: OK so first of all thank for answering, I really appreciate it. I would like to know why working with Tkinter and Qt in the same app is a mistake, and if so I assume there is a batter replacement for Tkinter. If i can ask that beside interacting with UI elements in terms of setting texts, does my worker build correctly or can I improve it ?

Comment: Btw I forgot to mention but my end game goal mainly with this Worker is to create a thread that will always run in the backround and will check if the QT field are empty and if so paint them to red color to notify the user that specific field are empty, when the user will enter any text the field will return to white again, how could have I implemented this correctly ?

Comment: Mixing GUI toolkits in general is a bad idea, since each of them run off their own independent even loops.  And as far as better replacements for tkinter... that is what Qt is.    As for the rest of your questions, please create a proper [mre] @ZoharHazoom

Comment: So basically the worker class is for 2 main reasons which are: 1) Creating a thread for functions to prevent GUI freezing, 2) hanle 4 signals which are Success, Fail, Error, Finish. The main thing I use with those signals is to handle the function correctly and second thing is to retrace function failures with the error signal. I have a though function that I use this worker and I have 0 problems and only happiness even though I draw values from Qwidgets so I wonder if the problem is when I am trying to set values in the main GUI through the thread ?

Comment: If you're running a thread to constantly check if the text fields are empty then you're doing it for a **terrible** reason. The event loop and the signals/slots mechanism is *exactly* made for that; just connect the `textChanged` signals of all those input fields to a function that checks all of them, then if *any* of that fields is empty, do whatever you need for that case, otherwise do the opposite. I strongly urge you to read more about event driven programming, Qt signal/slot mechanism and anything related to the Python GIL and threading.

Comment: @musicamante Wow I feel pritty stupid, I actually did not think about it. Thanks for commenting :)